# Error installing Elasticsearch 7 - Failed dependencies

Tags: elasticsearch, centos, installation

On my dedicated server I currently have Elasticsearch 6 installed. I would like to upgrade to Elasticsearch 7. I'm using the "Download and install the RPM Manually" method. Here's the link that explains the steps:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rpm.html

Here are my terminal steps:

```
[root@server ~]# wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm
--2019-04-18 17:19:20--  https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm
Resolving artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)... 2a04:4e42:2e::734, 151.101.198.222
Connecting to artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)|2a04:4e42:2e::734|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 346827255 (331M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm’

100%[=============================================================================================================================================>] 346,827,255  106MB/s   in 3.3s   

2019-04-18 17:19:43 (102 MB/s) - ‘elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm’ saved [346827255/346827255]

[root@server ~]# wget https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm.sha512
--2019-04-18 17:20:01--  https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm.sha512
Resolving artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)... 2a04:4e42:2e::734, 151.101.198.222
Connecting to artifacts.elastic.co (artifacts.elastic.co)|2a04:4e42:2e::734|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 160 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm.sha512’

100%[=============================================================================================================================================>] 160         --.-K/s   in 0s      

2019-04-18 17:20:01 (22.7 MB/s) - ‘elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm.sha512’ saved [160/160]

[root@server ~]# shasum -a 512 -c elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm.sha512
elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm: OK
[root@server ~]# sudo rpm --install elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm
warning: elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm: Header V4 RSA/SHA512 Signature, key ID d88e42b4: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    elasticsearch < 7.0.0 is obsoleted by elasticsearch-0:7.0.0-1.x86_64
```

Here are my server specifications:

Centos: 7.6

Java:
openjdk version "1.8.0_201"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.201-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the RPM repository previously? I'm not sure where else the `obsoleted by elasticsearch-0:7.0.0-1.x86_64` would be coming from otherwise.

If so I'd clean the cache directory, fetch all available versions, and then install the desired one:

```
yum clean all
yum --showduplicate list elasticsearch
yum install elasticsearch-0:7.0.0-1.x86_64
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. When I ran the three terminal commands, the first two ran without issue, but the third one I got:

No package elasticsearch-0:7.0.0-1.x86_64 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: In the root directory I do have the the following file:

elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm

Comment: Sorry forgot to answer your question, yes the RPM was added for Elasticsearch 6 and has been working fine for over a year.

Comment: The 3rd line was a bit of a wild guess. Use whatever the previous line is offering you. With the package repo you don't have to manually download RPMs

Comment: Thank you kindly. This installed Elasticsearch 7 perfectly: yum install elasticsearch-7.0.0-x86_64.rpm

Comment: Once Elasticsearch 7 is installed you will need to stop Elasticsearch 6 with this command: systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: Then start Elasticsearch with this command: service elasticsearch start

Comment: You can verify which version of Elasticsearch is running with this command: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'